# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib3.packages.six'

Tags: docker

I'm not able to run my airflow image. It builds successfully, but when I use docker-compose up and bring up the image, it throws the following error and exits.

```
Unable to load the config, contains a configuration error.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/logging/config.py", line 390, in resolve
    found = getattr(found, frag)
AttributeError: module 'airflow.utils.log' has no attribute 'file_task_handler'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/logging/config.py", line 392, in resolve
    self.importer(used)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/utils/log/file_task_handler.py", line 24, in <module>
    import requests
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    import urllib3
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .exceptions import (
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/exceptions.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .packages.six.moves.http_client import (
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib3.packages.six'
```

Of course I have googled around and found nothing that fixed it. I've tried fixing any possible errors with my dockerfile, restarting docker, rebuilding the image.

Here's a portion of my dockerfile.

```
RUN pip3 install  pytz --cert root.pem \
    && pip3 install pyOpenSSL --cert root.pem \
    && pip3 install ndg-httpsclient --cert root.pem \
    && pip3 install pyasn1 --cert root.pem \
    && pip3 install teradatasql --cert root.pem \
    && pip3 install --trusted-host=files.pythonhosted.org  --trusted-host=pypi.org apache-airflow[crypto,celery,postgres,hive,jdbc,kubernetes,mysql,mssql,ssh,ldap]==${AIRFLOW_VERSION} --cert root.pem \
    && pip3 install 'redis==3.2' --cert root.pem \
    && pip3 install Cython --cert root.pem \
    && pip3 install xmlrunner --cert root.pem \
    && pip3 install unittest-xml-reporting --cert root.pem \
    && pip3 install pyodbc --cert root.pem \
    && pip3 install flask-bcrypt --cert root.pem \
    && pip3 install python-ldap --cert root.pem \
    && pip3 install ldap3 --cert root.pem \
    && pip3 install emoji --cert root.pem \
    && pip3 install urllib3 --cert root.pem
```

Answer (score 1):

Added these lines to my dockerfile to fix the issue

```
    && pip3 uninstall urllib3 -y --cert root.pem \
    && pip3 install --no-cache-dir -U urllib3 --cert root.pem
```

Answer (score 0):

Lower version 1.24.1,Can solve this problem.
It is estimated that your version is 1.26

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31185748)

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with a docker image, what I did was to upgrade this packages on requeriments.txt:

requests,
six,
urllib3,

I did not specify the version and it worked fine

Answer (score 0):

Removing and installing the package again should resolve the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib3.packages.six'"`

```
# Remove Package
pip uninstall urllib3

# Install Package
pip install urllib3
```